# install Tomcat on remote server

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8, remote-server

What are the steps to install tomcat on remote server instead on localmachine.

following is present in server.xml file.

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

so do I need to replace "localhost" by "remote server ip"?

and are there some other changes to do?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you have seen any problems when doing so, that triggered this question. The installation doesn't differ between local and remote.

"localhost" in this case is the name of the `defaultHost`, i.e. when the virtual host name doesn't match any host that you have in your server.xml, the host named "localhost" will be chosen. This is sensible as a default, and you'll never know which hostnames you want to serve - if you serve them by IP, DNS name, or both of them.

On a remote server you typically want to run tomcat in the background, e.g. as daemon (*nix) or service (windows), rather than from the command line. And you definitely do not want to run as root. More often than not you want to run on ports 80 and 443, and the means to achieve that are many. I prefer piping the requests through a reverse proxy (e.g. Apache httpd). But this all has nothing to do with the installation of tomcat - going more into detail here would be far outside the scope of stackoverflow.